# result from /proc/self/exe is unfriendly in a clearcase view

Tags: clang, clearcase

If I execute a binary in a clearcase view, and look at /proc/self/exe for that on Linux, I see something like the following:

```
$ cd /proc/19220
$ ls -l exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 peeterj pdxdb2 0 2012-11-30 13:04 exe -> /home/peeterj/views/peeterj_clang-7.vws/.s/00024/8000028250b8f1d1llvm-config
```

The clang llvm-config program, not unreasonably, uses this output to try to figure out the absolute fully qualified path that it is located in (I assume in case argv[0] isn't fully qualified).

Is there a way to find the location within the view that this corresponds to.  For example, in this case, the llvm-config exe is actually in:

/vbs/bldsupp/linuxamd64/clang/debug/bin

(I'm wondering if it's feasible to modify clang's GetExecutablePath() function to figure this out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trivial solution here (for an old version of ClearCase though):

The technote "[PK27447: WITHIN A CLEARCASE DYNAMIC VIEW, THE READLINK() CALL ON LINUX RETURNS THE WRONG PATH FOR THE EXECUTABLE'S /PROC/SELF/EXE VALUE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK27447)" suggests:

> Local fix

> 1. Use `getcwd()`,  `get_current_dir_name()`, `getwd()` in applications slated for a VOB/View context
>    2. Create an interposer library to intercept the `readlink()` call, and modify to use any of the above calls to return the proper data

The cause:

> `/proc/self/exe` returns the improper path while `getcwd` succeeds.

> Unfortunately, for `/proc/self/exe` to return the proper value [from within a VOB/View context] would require a change within the Linux kernel to allow MVFS to "override" the present setting.

> IBM LTC has been working on having the Linux community adopt this change so that we can then incorporate the new features within MVFS.

Related: [Bug Sun 6189256](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6189256).